# Do I have to use " having " or "was"?

Tags: word-choice

Do I have to use having or was?

> He **is having blissful** that he had passed exam.

or

> He **was blissful** that he had passed exam.

Comment: You cannot *have* an adjective. *Blissful* is an adjective.

Comment: It is okay . but what I am troubling here is whether I have to use "is having" or the word "was". could you explain?

Comment: *having* is a form of the verb *to have*. *is having* usually means *is experiencing*, for example: "He is having a great time." You cannot follow *is having* with an adjective; you must use a noun phrase (like "a great time"). What makes you think that "is having blissful" could be correct? Did you see this written somewhere?

Comment: oh thank you so much for helping me, my English is not good, meaning I have to use "was blissful"? is this true?

Comment: "was blissful" is certainly a better choice. However, you should say "*the* exam". Also, I think *blissful* is a weird adjective to use in this context. I would normally use *blissful* to describe a situation or state rather than a person. For example: "He was in a blissful state after passing the exam." You could also say "He was happy that he had passed the exam."

Comment: Possibly the confusion is due to the OP's native language i.e. L1-L2 interference. In many languages "have " is used to mean "am" as it is used in English. @Mixolydian